# Connections with JavaMail

Tags: java, plugins, jakarta-mail

I am working with **JavaMail** for my plugin, within this plugin I am trying to send an email but my issue lies around the client. 
The client can't handle the plugin connecting to the email server and sending an email it either crashes the entire server or the client gets kicked out.
 My fix for this was instead of constantly connecting to the email server and sending an email why not simply keep one connection open when the plugin starts and grab that connection when I am wanting to send an email hopefully this will help in allowing the client and server to stay stable without any crashes. 
If anyone can help me I am just curious on how I can go about keeping a a single connection open and grabbing it when it is needed and then closing it when the plugin gets disabled.

What I have tried:

```
private Session session;

public void connect() {

    String provider = plugin.getConfig().getString("EmailProvider");
    String email = plugin.getConfig().getString("Email");
    String password = plugin.getConfig().getString("Password");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", provider);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(email, password);
                }
            });
}

private boolean checkSession() {
    try {
        if (session != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String text) {

    if (!checkSession()) {
        connect();
        System.out.println("connecting");
    }
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(text);

        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What was the original error before your fix?

Comment: There was not error, the issue was the client can't handle a connection to the mail server and an email sending without the client getting kicked out of the server due to "timing out"

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is, you can't.

There's no way to force a connection to remain open.  Connections can be closed for all sorts of reasons and your program needs to be prepared for that.

You can, however, cache an open connection and reuse it as long as it's still connected.  But without knowing what your plugin plugs in to, it's hard to describe the best strategy for that.

Note also that mail servers really don't want you to keep a connection open if you're not using it, which is why they'll close it out from under you if you leave it open but idle for too long.  And artificially keeping the connection active won't win you any points with the mail server either.

If your mail server crashes when you connect to it, it's probably time to get a new mail server.

Comment: Well what about opening that connection and grabbing it for use, and when I grab it for use have a method to check if the connection is still open if its not let's re-connect and then send that email ? And then at least the odd person may end up timing out of the server rather than every single person.

Comment: Right, that's the caching approach.  You can never depend on the connection being live, but often it will be.  And remember that it may fail *while* you're using it.

Comment: The way I have shown above, is that the correct way about opening a connection and grabbing it and using it ?

Comment: What you're doing above isn't doing anything with connections.  It's just managing the Session, which is just a local configuration artifact.  The connection is opened, used, and closed inside the Transport.send method.  If you want to manage the connection yourself, you need to cache a Transport object instance instead of using the static Transport.send method.

Comment: [link]https://hastebin.com/gejekohuho.cs                                                          How about now, is that the way to go about keeping a connection open then check if it closes if it does just connect again? Also I seem to be getting an error on that one check not sure on why.. I did point to which line it was on the hastebin though!

Comment: You only need to create the Session once, not for every connection.  And [use Session.getInstance](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  You'll want to call the Transport.send method that takes host, user name, and password, and not set those properties.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Hey I figured it out, after many tries it kept giving off errors and I kept checking my code over and over again and did not understand why I ended up disabling my fire-wall and that had seemed to fix the entire issue between the plugin and it's connectivity between the mail server. My question is for other people who have their fire-walls setup (if you know what to do in this case) what should I tell them to do to allow for the plugin to connect to the mail server without any issues? (Like what should they add to their firewall or disable etc..) Thank you for all your help, I appreciated!

Comment: Not many people are going to reconfigure or disable their firewall for your plugin unless you’re “really special”.  You’re going to need to be able to reconfigure your plugin to work in whatever network environment it finds itself in.  Search the JavaMail FAQ for “proxy”.